# SEC7111 issue in IE9 complaining about https content

Tags: php, security, https, internet-explorer-9

I get an error in IE9 when my page is loaded in https, it's not like the other threads around here where content is loaded from for ex. http://googleapis.. I've switched all links to be protocol-relative so just //googleapis..

The error I get is from a picture I have on my page, which is loaded from the domain like so;

```
<img src="<?php echo getRootAddress();?>/images/img.jpg">
```

This will produce a https link and that's what I find confusing, that IE is saying:

> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
>   https://mydomain.se/images/img.jpg

I'd buy it if the link was just http:// and I have a bunch of other pictures that works fine, and of course I only get this in IE =) Any ideas?

Comment: It clearly looks like IE9 is a wuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance i would say this looks like a bug in IE (Gasp,  that never happens!).  To look into the issue i recommend using chrome with [Dom Snitch](http://code.google.com/p/domsnitch/),  which will provide accurate and detailed information into mixed content problems.

On a side note,  why are you using getRootAddress()?  That is a huge mess,  you should be using relative urls,  like this:

```
<img src="/images/img.jpg">
```

If the page is https,  this image will be loaded with https.   Relative URLs are a common software requirement,  I know this is something that is required at my place of work.

Comment: I don't get any issues in chrome but I'll look into Dom Snitch thanks for the tip! Actually I didn't write that part of the code so I'm not sure why we don't use a relative url.. Removed that and the error msg is gone - so thanks!